# The Killing form of a Lie algebra is $DER(\mathfrak{g})$-invariant

Tags: lie-algebras, differential-forms, semisimple-lie-algebras, casimir-tensors

The Killing form of a Lie algebra is defined as

$$
B(x,y)=\operatorname{Trace} (\operatorname{ad}_x \circ \operatorname{ad}_y)
$$
I'm trying to show that, given a derivation of the Lie algebra, i.e. $\phi \in \mathfrak{gl(g)} $ such that $[\phi(x),y]+[x,\phi(y)]=0$ we have
$$
B(\phi(x),y)+B(x,\phi(y))=0
$$

Thanks to the Jacobi identity i have proven the result for any $\phi \in \operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak{g})$, but i can't see how to expand the proof to all the derivations of the lie algebra.

EDIT: the question is a duplicate of [Proof of an identity for the Killing form involving derivations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159976/proof-of-an-identity-for-the-killing-form-involving-derivations). I can't vote to close it because the question has no accepted answer, but the proof is in the comments

Comment: For a proof see the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159976/proof-of-an-identity-for-the-killing-form-involving-derivations).